# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectsUtil.isM2eWtpDisabled

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e-wtp

I am using eclipse kepler with maven v4.0.0 and jboss 7.0 and JDK 1.6. I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectsUtil.isM2eWtpDisabled(Lorg/eclipse/m2e/core/project/IMavenProjectFacade;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.internal.configurators.JaxRsProjectConfigurator.isConfigurationEnabled(JaxRsProjectConfigurator.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.internal.configurators.JaxRsProjectConfigurator.configureInternal(JaxRsProjectConfigurator.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.internal.configurators.JaxRsProjectConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(JaxRsProjectConfigurator.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.mavenProjectChanged(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.refresh(MavenProjectManager.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Was it working fine before or you are doing it for the first time?
What plugins do you have already installed?

Comment: it is working with out issues but when ever i update the maven it is showing this error. plugins are m2e-wtp & m2e connector

Comment: Check if an update to m2e-wtp is available

Comment: when do u get this error, on build or while loading in eclipse only? which version of maven used maven 2 or maven 3? m2e connector is eclipse plugin. So does project builds on command prompt?

Comment: I believe a full list of plugins in the namespace org.eclipse.m2e.wtp with exact versions would be needed to figure out the problem. Looks like ...m2e.wtp.jaxrs is incompatible with the rest of ...m2e.wtp

Answer (score 3):

You can use m2e 1.5.0 from marketplace
or you can use this approach:

- Go to:

  Preferences->Click Maven->Click Templates

Now you can see the list of templates,un-check all the templates of wtp i.e ***m2e-wtp-activation*** ....

Now you can clean install the project

Comment: Please don't hesitate to mark the question as answered, if the above has helped :)

Comment: Preferences → Maven → Templates does not exist in Eclipse 2022-12 M1 (4.26.0 M1)

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete .m2 folder in your computer and clean the project then it will automatically create it.

Next check the below settings are there in .project file

[image: .project]

Next check the settings in .classpath file
[image]

If nothing worked above. Please try to use Eclipse Luna version, it will work. I had some problem with maven 3.5 with kepler then i tried using luna, it worked for me.

I hope this helps for you!

Comment: I disagree, NoSuchMethodError thrown from a plugin is an installation error, nothing that can be fixed by project configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the m2e-wtp plugin fixed this for me (I don't even know what it does or when I downloaded it).